# How to solve Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, kotlin, junit

I have an existing Kotlin project. I am running Java 11.

Recently I updated it with `mvn -U clean install`, and this particular test stopped working.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension

    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
    @SpringBootTest
    class QuickCheck {
    
        @Test
        fun loadContext() {
    
        }
    
    }
```

I have many dependencies but the most relevant to this case, I think, are:

- spring-cloud-context: 2.2.6.RELEASE
- spring-cloud-kubernetes-config: 1.1.7.RELEASE
- spring-cloud-kubernetes-core: 1.1.7.RELEASE
- spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config: 1.1.7.RELEASE

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
> at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)    at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
> at
> com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined
> in class path resource
> [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
> [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans]
> from ClassLoader
> [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3b192d32]    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:761)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:566)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:144)
> at
> org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:212)
> at
> org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117)
> at
> org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:362)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
> ... 67 more

I tried looking into StackOverflow and in Spring projects, but I cannot triage this issue.

Comment: What version of junit you using?

Comment: Sorry, I noticed you using junit5 from the debug logs. Have you migrated from the junit4 recently? I will give a try in free time to build a simple pom with java11+ junit5. Anyways, if you using openjdk java 11 is no longer maintained. Good time to upgrade to java 16 until java 17 LTS releases in early August.

Comment: @bh4r4th I think that problem was in one of the libraries I used. `spring-cloud-*`, unsure what that was. Also, openjdk11 finished public support of java11, java11 is still a major player on the market among other LTS versions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history

Comment: Cool. Will create a sample project locally over weekend to see whether I can reproduce this issue with dependencies or stack you mentioned. I will get back to you with results.

Comment: Sharing a specific pom which is close to your project would be helpful to others in investigating too.

Answer (score 0):

**Looks good as per the stack you mentioned.**

I have created this pom.xml to replicate your versions and edited the test context file to match your test class. Looks good to me.

```
2021-06-17 12:42:50.845  INFO 86868 --- [main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-06-17 12:42:51.141  INFO 86868 --- [main] com.greenbird.demo.DemoApplicationTests  : Started DemoApplicationTests in 3.722 seconds (JVM running for 5.082)
***
Test::loadContext()::Loads and runs perfectly 
***
2021-06-17 12:42:51.597  INFO 86868 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

**Worth Trying:**

- Try to delete the `target` folder and do a mvn clean install.
- You can also try removing `<version />` tags for `spring-cloud-*` dependecies and delete `target` folder before running `mvn clean install` which should download compatible versions to your `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>` version mentioned in the `<parent />`. Then adjust versions accordingly.

**NOTE:**
I used `AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9` java installed via `sdkman` using  `sdk install java 11.0.11.j9-adpt`.

**Pom I used to test**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<!--        <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>-->
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.greenbird</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for testing spring test context</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.72</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring cloud   -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-kubernetes-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- junit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Let me know, if you there is a version difference with respect to your project. like if you using a different `kotlin` version or some other dependency. I will try to load and run again.